# Installed pydev in eclipse, but there is no new python project option

Tags: apt, python, eclipse

I've noticed a package called eclipse-pydev is available.  I run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
sudo apt-get install eclipse-pydev
```

After doing this and running eclipse I do not see a way to start a python project.  Is there an intermediate package I need to install to make this work?  (e.g to run a C/C++ compiler in eclipse the following two packages have to be installed.)

```
sudo apt-get install eclipde-cdt
sudo apt-get install eclipse-jdt
```

Also I am aware of the official way to install pydev.  http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html.

Comment: Running Version 3.8.1

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? Is 3.8.1 the latest packaged version of eclipse? What version of pydev?

Comment: I'm running 16.04.  I've looked into it some more and it appears to be an issue with Eclipse 3.8 having forward-compatibility issues.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879334/pydev-perspective-not-showing-after-install-on-eclipse-3-8.   Pydev 4.5.5 is the last version that will work with Eclipse 3.8.

Comment: I believe I installed the latest packaged version of eclipse.  (e.g. apt-get update before apt-get install eclipse)

Comment: It might be better to install Eclipse and PyDev directly from their sites rather than rely on packagers.

Comment: That is what I too ultimately concluded.   Ended up directly installing PyCharm which is an excellent IDE (some tinkering required).  For complete Python beginners I would recommend Thonny.